# I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to automate a forum using POM in Selenium... how can I fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I'm trying to use POM for a web page I'm trying to automate and I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I added TestNG as well as any jar files to Selenium. Anyway, here's the code:

The first one is from a file I named Forumloginapplication.java in a package known as testcases

```
package testcases;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import objectrepository.SimpleProgrammerForum;

public class Forumloginapplication {

    @Test
    public void Login() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://simpleprogrammer.com/members/");

        SimpleProgrammerForum sp=new SimpleProgrammerForum(driver);
        sp.Loginnav().click();
        sp.Userid().sendKeys("10asmock");
        sp.Userpass().sendKeys("secret");
        sp.Rememberme().click();
        sp.Login_button().click();
    }

}
```

This one is named SimpleProgrammerForum.java in a package known as objectrepository:

```
package objectrepository;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class SimpleProgrammerForum {

    WebDriver driver;

    public SimpleProgrammerForum(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    By login_navbar=By.xpath("//span[@class='p-navgroup-linkText'][contains(text(),'Log in')]");
    By username=By.name("login");
    By password=By.name("password");
    By login_checkbox=By.name("remember");
    By login_button=By.className("button-text");

    public WebElement Loginnav() {
        return driver.findElement(login_navbar);
    }

    public WebElement Userid() {
        return driver.findElement(username);
    }

    public WebElement Userpass() {
        return driver.findElement(password);
    }

    public WebElement Rememberme() {
        return driver.findElement(login_checkbox);
    }

    public WebElement Login_button() {
        return driver.findElement(login_button);
    }

}
```

Another thing I get when I run the program is a popup which tells me: "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again." followed by another popup which states: "A Java Exception has occurred."

Comment: Regarding your JNI error: Please do not mix two problems in one question. You can post another question with more information about your environment (OS, Eclipse and JDK including versions)

Answer (score 0):

TestNG has a JCommander dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.14.3</version>
  <name>testng</name>
  <description>A testing framework for the JVM</description>
  <url>http://testng.org</url>
...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
      <version>1.72</version>
    </dependency>
...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

You will need to use Maven or add all TestNG dependencies manually as jar files.